# Running multiple tests on the same jenkins pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline where I run tests on the main branch of the GitHub Project. Now I want to run a diff. branch as well let us say okta branch(the build should trigger automatically since I run them at odd times). Can I do this in the same pipeline, there is a plugin known as multi-branch pipeline but it includes all the branches and I don't want that since our
project contains lots of branches. Also, I want them to be running at diff. times for this I am using the parameterized scheduler plugin. Can someone please tell me how to run two branches in the same pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter like `BRANCHNAME`, and use it on git checkout like so: `${BRANCHNAME}`. This way, you can run the pipeline (using parametrized scheduler) to run different branches on different schedules:

```
30 0 * * * %BRANCHNAME=okta
30 6 * * * %BRANCHNAME=auth0
30 12 * * * %BRANCHNAME=master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a Multibranch Pipeline and add a Branch filter to filter the branches you need. You can either use, `Filter by name (with regular expression)` or `Filter by name (with wildcards)` options for this.

[image]